# Making .NET Wrapper For DLL

Tags: c#, c++

I have a DLL that was created in C++ using Qt. But I have the project files to open it in Visual Studio and edit it and whatnot. I want to be able to use this library in a C# application that I'm making. So, what do I need to do to the project to make it referable in a C# application?

I'm reading all sorts of things about PInvoke, making a .NET wrapper, etc. and I'm not sure what the best option is and how to do it.

Comment: Do you have access to the source?

Comment: Yes I do. I have the entire project.

Comment: Ok. I made a .NET wrapper for C++ classes last week, but I could only get it working when I compiled the source in a C++/CLI project which contained both the native classes (*.hpp, *.cpp) as well as my managed C++ classes (`public ref class Foo {};`)

Comment: I should add that it works just fine if you add the files to your project as links instead of making duplicates into the C++/CLI project

Comment: Okay so what exactly is my next step?

Comment: Is your code in a Visual Studio project already?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm looking up how to make a wrapper and it looks fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make .NET wrapper classes for C++ classes by making a new C++/CLI project in your solution and for each class you actually need a wrapper for, add a new item `Managed.ClassName.cpp` and check out the pattern below.

**Managed.Rand.cpp** (this will be a new file in your C++/CLI project, and assumes your native project is called 'Logic' and the `Rand` class is in the `Logic` namespace)

```
#include "../Logic/Rand.cpp"

using namespace System;

namespace Logic {
    namespace Managed {
        public ref class Rand {
            Logic::Rand * rand;
        public:
            Rand(UInt32 seed) { rand = new Logic::Rand(seed); }
            !Rand() { delete rand; }
            ~Rand() { this->!Rand(); }

            // Wrapper methods
            UInt32 Next() { return rand->Next(); }
        };
    }
}
```

Remember that the `!ClassName` method (sort of a destructor)  causes the class to automatically implement `IDisposable`, so you should wrap your instances of `Managed.ClassName` in a using construct or call `Dispose` on them when you're done. In short, the usual `IDisposable`  usage patterns apply here.